# psql throws Error at Line:1, when trying to execute sql file. But, the same sql file runs fine in pgadmin

Tags: postgresql, psql, pgadmin

We have a bigger SQL file containing tables, stored procedures, views. The file is running fine in the PGADMIN 4.8.

But, when the same script is run using PSQL, getting below error:

> ÿ_/
> psql:C:/FolderName/FileName.sql:1: ERROR:
> syntax error at or near "ÿ_"
> LINE 1: ÿ_/

Even if I try to move the sql code few lines below , after adding comment, I am still getting error line number as Line 1.

Is this encoding issue ? How to handle this ?

Comment: What exactly is `ÿ_/` doing there and why do you think it should be valid sql?

Comment: It is valid sql, because the same file is running fine in the pgadmin. Also, I dont have `ÿ_/`, in the file

Comment: You have just posted `ÿ_/` above and it is in the error message. If that isn't in your file, then why are you posting an error message from something else?

Comment: no. I am pasting from the error message of the same file only. I am also confused why this character comes up

Comment: All that time people spend on docs that no one reads. See [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) *Notes for Windows Users*.